# How to display values selected in a multiselect listbox in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have been trying to solve this. Everything else is just error. 
This is the closest, but it only show the last selected item in the listbox.

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To SVSListBox1.ListCount - 1 
If SVSListBox1.Selected(i) Then SelectedItemText = SVSListBox1(i) 
End if
Next i
```

SVSListBox.Value = SelectedItemText
Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(startingRow, 12).Value = SVSListBox1.value

Posted with IPhone. (Sorry cause my PC is locked so I had to type it manually in my IPhone)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if you're asking this but if you need to know how to write the selected items from a `ListBox` to your `Worksheet`, then the code below might be a starting point for you:

```
Dim index As Integer
Dim cell As Range

Set cell = Sheet1.Range("A1")
For index = 0 To UserForm1.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If UserForm1.ListBox1.Selected(index) Then
        cell.Value = UserForm1.ListBox1.List(index)
        Set cell = cell.Offset(1)
    End If
Next
```

**Updated for comma separated items**

```
Dim index As Integer
Dim items As String

For index = 0 To UserForm1.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If UserForm1.ListBox1.Selected(index) Then
        If items <> vbNullString Then items = items & ", "
        items = items & UserForm1.ListBox1.List(index)
    End If
Next

Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = items
```

Comment: Yes! This is what I wanted. But is there a way for me to display the values selected into a single cell? With common used to separate them. @Ambie

Comment: I see, this is how it is done! This is what I wanted! Thank you!! @Ambie